# Custom authentication for Elmah in .net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, elmah, elmah.mvc

I have a mvc project but I use a custom membership provider which I cannot integrate with Elmah.

What I want is a way for me to make sure only admins can reach mydomain.com/Elmah

So either if I can get Elmah to check with my membership provider (which has nothing to do with any microsoft membership) or more likely if I can setup in web.config that that particular path requires separate authentication of some sort.

I am fine with having a separate user for accessing Elmah

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the web.config, in `<appSettings>` include this

`<add key="elmah.mvc.requiresAuthentication" value="true" />`

and in the `<elmah>` section include this

`<security allowRemoteAccess="yes" />`

now if you access mydomain.com/Elmah you get a pop up to enter your credentials. You can use  the windows username/password of the machine on which you hosted the website.

Comment: That is exactly what I am looking for, but my plan is to host on azure, how will it work there?

Comment: Try the username/password given in the publish settings. When you login into your portal and navigate to your website your should see a "Download the publish profile" on the right. This file has username and password, try using those.

Comment: Excellent, sadly I don't have time to test for a few days but will remember to mark as answer if it works.

Comment: is there a way to configure certain users access only?

Comment: ok found the solution, nevermind
    <add key="elmah.mvc.allowedRoles" value="*" />
    <add key="elmah.mvc.allowedUsers" value="*" />

Comment: Sorry for the delay in accepting answer, but as usual a million things to do. It works like a charm in combination with kiev's comment